# System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException when program is deployed

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio-2010

At the moment I'm working on a program that can detect an USB-device when connected. Copy all the files and directories of that device to a specified folder. All of this works. I build this program, no problem there. When I run the .exe on my Windows 7 laptop ( with one partition) the program does what it's supposed to do. When I test the same program on another Windows 7 laptop (with two partitions ) and a Windows vista laptop ( with two partitions ) I get this error message ( in Dutch ):

```
System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: De index valt buiten het bereik. Deze mag niet negatief zijn en moet kleiner zijn dan de grootte van de verzameling.
Parameternaam: index
   bij System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentOutOfRangeException()
   bij System.Collections.Generic.List`1.get_Item(Int32 index)
   bij PHL___USB_tool.USBTool.LoadDownloadItems() in C:\Users\2930682\Desktop\ONDERZOEK CopyFormatUSB\MyProgram\PHL - USB tool\PHL - USB tool\USB tool.cs:regel 162
   bij PHL___USB_tool.USBTool.WndProc(Message& m) in C:\Users\2930682\Desktop\ONDERZOEK CopyFormatUSB\MyProgram\PHL - USB tool\PHL - USB tool\USB tool.cs:regel 70
   bij System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   bij System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   bij System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
```

If I check my code: for line 70

**EDIT:** this function will be called/receives messages of Windows 7 operating system.

```
    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        if (m.Msg == Native.WM_DEVICECHANGE)
        {
            if (m.WParam.ToInt32() == Native.DBT_DEVICEARRIVAL)
            {
                if (!_blnLoading)
                {
                     switch (tabControl1.SelectedIndex)
                    {
                        case 0: SetProgress(_lstPictures);
                                lblCopies.Visible = false;
                                LoadDownloadItems();
                                break;
                        case 1: SetProgress(_lstPictures2);
                                LoadUploadItems();
                                break;
                        case 2: SetProgress(_lstPictures3);
                                LoadDeleteItems();
                                break;
                    }
                }
            }
            else if (m.WParam.ToInt32() == Native.DBT_DEVICEREMOVECOMPLETE)
            {
                _blnLoading = false;

                _alreadyConnectedVolumes = null;
                _alreadyConnectedVolumes = new VolumeDeviceClass();
            }
        }
        base.WndProc(ref m);
    }
```

and my code for line 162

**EDIT:** this function cross checks the `_alreadyConnectedVolumes.Devices` that is filled when the program starts with the `volumeDeviceClass.Devices` when the `LoadDownloadItems()` is called. To check and select the newly added device. After that check if it is an USB-device with the `IsUsb` function.

**EDIT:** in `_lstPictures` are three Pictureboxes that are put in there when the program starts.

```
 private void LoadDownloadItems()
    {
        _blnLoading = true;
        lblErrorDestination.Visible = false;
        picErrorDestination.Visible = false;
        _intFilesCopied = 0;
        _intDirectoriesCopied = 0;

        VolumeDeviceClass volumeDeviceClass = new VolumeDeviceClass();

        int position = -1; // need it for control, when to stop the for-loop
        for (int i = 0; i < volumeDeviceClass.Devices.Count; i++)
        {
            if (position != -1)
                break;
            else
            {
                string logicalDrive = ((Volume)volumeDeviceClass.Devices[i]).LogicalDrive;

                for (int j = 0; j < _alreadyConnectedVolumes.Devices.Count; j++)
                {
                    if (((Volume)_alreadyConnectedVolumes.Devices[i]).LogicalDrive != logicalDrive)
                    {
                        position = i;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        // you don't need to check the position!
        // cause every new device during run-time, will be a removable device or usb-device
        if (position != -1 && volumeDeviceClass.Devices[position].IsUsb)
        {
            _connectedDevice = volumeDeviceClass.Devices[position];
            _strLogicalDrive = ((Volume) _connectedDevice).LogicalDrive;

            _lstPictures[0].Image = Properties.Resources.Pass;
            lblFirst.Text = "Usb-device (" + _strLogicalDrive + @"\) found";
            lblFirst.Refresh();
            RefreshProgress(_lstPictures);

            if (_strDestination != null)
            {
                GetDirectories(_strLogicalDrive);

                _lstPictures[1].Image = Properties.Resources.Pass;
                _lstPictures[2].Image = Properties.Resources.Pass;
                RefreshProgress(_lstPictures);

                lblCopies.Visible = true;
                lblCopies.Text = "Files copied: " + _intFilesCopied + "\tDirectories copied: " + _intDirectoriesCopied;
            }
            else
            {
                _lstPictures[1].Image = Properties.Resources.Error;
                _lstPictures[2].Image = Properties.Resources.Error;
                RefreshProgress(_lstPictures);

                lblErrorDestination.Visible = true;
                picErrorDestination.Visible = true;
            }

            UsbEject();

            _lstPictures[3].Image = Properties.Resources.Pass;
            RefreshProgress(_lstPictures);
        }
    }
```

**EDIT:** Some extra information tested my program again on two seperate laptops. The laptops have the same resources ( same operating sytem (windows 7 service pack 1), both HP EliteBook 8530p, ... ) this are the results:

My laptop ( were the program works perfectly ):

`_alreadyConnectedVolumes.Devices` exists of :

- C:\ --> harddisk
- D:\ --> DVD-rw-station

`volumeDeviceClass.Devices` exists of :

- C:\ --> harddisk
- D:\ --> DVD-rw-station
- E:\ --> my USB-drive --> this is the one were I can do actions with without problems!

The laptop of my mate ( were I get the error shown in this topic ):

`_alreadyConnectedVolumes.Devices` exists of :

- C:\ --> harddisk (partition 1 = primary )
- D:\ --> harddisk ( partition 2 )
- E:\ --> DVD-rw-station

`volumeDeviceClass.Devices` exists of :

- C:\ --> harddisk (partition 1 = primary )
- D:\ --> harddisk ( partition 2 )
- E:\ --> DVD-rw-station
- G:\ --> my USB-drive

In the two cases described here I used the same USB-device!

**EDIT: (Solved?)** this solved my problem, I think, I must check it tomorrow if it exactly works. But for now this solved the problems of the nested loops:

```
for (int i = 0; i < _alreadyConnectedVolumes.Devices.Count; i++)
        {

            string logicalDrive = ((Volume)_alreadyConnectedVolumes.Devices[i]).LogicalDrive;

            for (int j = 0; j < volumeDeviceClass.Devices.Count; j++)
            {
                if (logicalDrive == ((Volume)volumeDeviceClass.Devices[j]).LogicalDrive)
                    volumeDeviceClass.Devices.RemoveAt(j);
            }
        }
```

After this I just need to read out the `volumeDeviceClass.Devices` were is just one item in it! Cause my progrem let's you only registrate on USB-device at a time.

Can anyone tell me what causes the error. Cause can't think of one but a bug maybe?

Comment: Can you check for `_alreadyConnectedVolumes.Devices[i]` here count of devices might be less than `i`, you can check `i` and `j`, `i` shouldn't be greater than `j`

Comment: @AmarPalsapure When the programs starts on my laptop `_alreadyConnectedVolumes.Devices[i]` contains the C:\, D:\ and E:\ drive. When `volumeDeviceClass.Devices` is filled it contains C:\, D:\, E:\ and the F:\ drive, the last one is the newley connected USB-drive that I want to use

Answer (score 1):

In `if (((Volume)_alreadyConnectedVolumes.Devices[i]).LogicalDrive != logicalDrive)` you use `i` as index instead of `j`!

Comment: Yes, also noticed by someone on the msdn forum. But didn't solve the problem. But by noticing that problem, I figured that er is something wrong with my for-loops in total... trying to fix that, keep you all posted

Comment: The for loops didn't do exactly want they supposed to do. For a pc with just one parition it wasn't a problem. For multiple partitions it gave the error, this code fixed my problem is in my original question!

Answer (score 0):

This is mostly a guess, but I'm thinking that in some cases, your `position` variable isn't being set.  Try changing this:

```
if (volumeDeviceClass.Devices[position].IsUsb)
```

to this

```
if (position != -1 && volumeDeviceClass.Devices[position].IsUsb)
```

**Edit**: Also ensure that `_lstPictures` has three records in it.

Comment: Thanks Matt for the quick reply... I will try that and post the results.

There are always three recrods in _lstPictures... in the Onload it get's filled.

Comment: Tried the solution Matt suggested. Didn't work, still the same error.
Checked with the debugger, `_lstPictures` gets filled and has three PictureBox's in it.

Some more information:
LoadDownloadItems() gets called when a new devices is plugged in. In `_alreadyConnectedVolumes` the connected devices and hard disks are stored when the program starts. So when LoadDownloadItems() is called, I fill `volumeDeviceClass.Devices`. I cross check those two, to check which device is new and after that check if it's a USB-device.

Other idea's or solution are welcome to solve this problem.

Thanks Martijn

Comment: What is the type of `Devices`?

Comment: `Devices` is a method that gives back a `List<Device>` and the class `Device` contains the information about a usb-device or a harddisk such as naam, logicaldrive, and so on